# Calculated Formula to auto populate next PO# available when only one specific choice is selected from another column

Tags: calculated-column

I would like a calculated formula for the following: I have a column with a dropdown that will list Vendors to choose from. Only one of the Vendors needs a PO#. I'd like a column to auto calculate the next PO# available but ONLY when one particular vendor is selected.

Comment: Please include whether you are using SharePoint Online in O365 or specific version on-premises SharePoint Server.  Also add where does the calculation look to find previous PO# and what calculation is necessary to determine what constitutes "Next" -- is it just sequential and a number needs incremented?

Comment: We are using SharePoint Online in O365.

Comment: I'd like the calculation to somehow look at previous line items in the same column to determine what the next sequential number would be. But only rows with a specific choice in a dropdown list would have a PO# displayed. Example: this would be a credit card receipt tracker. There would be multiple vendors to choose from (or add). Only items that choose Amazon as the vendor would require a PO# that I would ideally like auto-generated with the next sequential number. If the vendor selected was Vistaprint, then no PO# would need to generate.

Comment: Formulas in the built-in Calculated column type do not have any mechanism to look up values in other items.  Since you are online, are you open to building a Flow in Power Automate?